# Ресурсы для изучения web-разработки

Tags: java, html, python, css, веб-программирование

Я хочу заниматься web-разработкой, но не знаю с чего начать. Начал изучать Python, т.к. он очень простой и даёт большие возможности для web-разработки. Прошу посоветовать ресурсы для изучения JavaScript, HTML, CSS.

Comment: google.com - лучший ресурс

Comment: любой разработчик, особенно начинающий, должен стать мастером спорта по гуглению.
Поставьте себе цель и начните делать. Например сделать сайт. Заходим на ютуб и набираем. Делаем первый сайт на python. И Вам будет куча ссылок. Начинайте изучать.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WGIzvVwUfYs&t=319s
Вот неплохой видос от блоггера, разраба на эту тему. Не реклама, но для себя можешь почерпнуть много полезного. От себя могу посовеьовать курс Html academy, которые сам прохожу. Вполне себе качественное образование

Comment: [Думаю будет полезно.](https://github.com/kamranahmedse/developer-roadmap)
Не совсем ресурсы для изучения, но зато будет подробный план, а дальше гуглить, и гуглить, и гулить...

Comment: https://html5book.ru/ для того чтобы изучить html/css <br>
https://learn.javascript.ru/ для JS. Не обязательно её сразу всю читать, а то задолбаешься) <br>
Ну и, конечно, практиковаться надо много.

Comment: Подобного рода вопросы рассматриваются в отдельных, специально выделенных топиках, которые поддерживаются сообществом.